# Extra Process file locks

Tags: .net, access-control, file-locking

I have a .NET system where I need to allow files to be locked and unlocked across process boundaries. The model I plan to use is this:

1. User generate a lock token
2. Uses Locks a file with token and refreshes token
3. repeat at #2 as needed
4. Uses unlocks all files by releasing token
5. If uses fails to refresh token in some time-frame, #4 happens automatically

Each step can be done from a different process.

The question is two fold: *is this a reasonable model and are there any readily available tools for implementing it?* If this can't be directly done in the OS, I'm thinking of some sort of advisory locking with `.file`s or the like.

*Edit: this mode gets non-exclusive read locks, but other modes could get exclusive write locks but they would always be released by the same process that got them.*

Comment: Do you need to use files specifically? Why not a named Mutex? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx

Comment: Do you want a reader-writer or an exclusive lock?

Comment: @Tim: that wont work as the Mutex is released on thread exit.

Comment: I think [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/640122/is-there-a-global-named-reader-writer-lock) might answer it for you.