# Non threadlocked Mutex

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, mutex

This is an offshoot of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804356/extra-process-file-locks/) question but with a few constraints removed.

I have a system where I need to manage file locking. I need to be able to lock a file (shared read locking) in one thread and then unlock it in another. More accurately, I can't be sure what thread it will be unlocked in or even if the creating thread is still around.

I will also need exclusive write locking to go with this but that will be all in the same thread.

the [.NET Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) won't work as it does extra stuff when the creating thread exits

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a (named) [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx) with a count of one? `WaitOne` to lock, `Release` to unlock?

Comment: see edit: forgot to mention I'm looking for shared locks. Aside from that +1

Answer (score 1):

The question that you linked to is crossing process boundaries, but from what I read you are only crossing threads...  with this in mind I think that Jeff Richter's ReaderWriterGate class might fit your problem well.  It allows you to control access to a shared resource and queue access requests to the resource.  It doesn't seem to have any thread affinity so if you are not crossing process boundaries you it might be a solution for you.

Here is a link to an article about the class...  [Concurrent affairs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163532.aspx) and you can download the [PowerThreading Library from here](http://www.wintellect.com/PowerThreading.aspx)

If your case is really simple (except for the locking from one thread and releasing from another) I don't see why you couldn't use the built in [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx) in .NET (although the one in the PowerThreading library is supposed to be much faster).  The [Monitor class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) has no thread affinity and can be accessed from any context so depending on how you are using it this may be your most straight forward solution.

Comment: I'll take a look at them. The MSDN links  sound more like what I really want.

Comment: Gerrr... ReaderWriterLock, ReaderWriterLockSlim and Monitor are all thread locked. :(

Comment: Did you look at Richter's stuff?

Comment: I'm not really in a position to drag in external dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a *Turnstile* problem. You need to manage the readers going in with the first one locking the file and the last one to leave unlocking the file. You can use a semaphore to implement this.
You can give preference to the writer by having the turnstile deny readers while there is a writer waiting.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but I haven't found a way to do it where  the locking and unlocking can happen in different threads (Thread A locks, thread B unlocks)

Comment: You could have a custom semaphore that locks the file when the first token is taken and then unlocks the file when the last token is returned.

Comment: Just to clarify, the read lock is then maintained by the semaphore so it is not actually held by a thread as such. The first thread effectively opens the gate and then the last thread closes it this is managed by the semaphore when the token count is incremented from 0 or decremented to 0, the threads themselves do not know whether they are the ones who are opening or closing the gate.