# Finding or building an inter-process broadcast communication channel

Tags: c#, .net, c++, ipc, broadcast

So we have this somewhat unusual need in our product.  We have numerous processes running on the local host and need to construct a means of communication between them.  The difficulty is that ...

1. There is no 'server' or master process
2. Messages will be broadcast to all listening nodes
3. Nodes are all Windows processes, but may be C++ or C#
4. Nodes will be running in both 32-bit and 64-bit simultaneously
5. Any node can jump in/out of the conversation at any time
6. A process abnormally terminating should not adversely affect other nodes
7. A process responding slowly should also not adversely affect other nodes
8. A node does not need to be 'listening' to broadcast a message

*A few more important details...*

The 'messages' we need to send are trivial in nature.  A name of the type of message and a single string argument would suffice.

The communications are not necessarily secure and do not need to provide any means of authentication or access control; however, we want to group communications by a Windows Log-on session.  Perhaps of interest here is that a non-elevated process should be able to interact with an elevated process and vise-versa.

My first question: is there an existing open-source library?, or something that can be used to fulfill this with little effort.  As of now I haven't been able to find anything :(

If a library doesn't exist for this then... What technologies would you use to solve this problem?  Sockets, named-pipes, memory mapped files, event handles?  It seems like connection based transports (sockets/pipes) would be a bad idea in a fully connected graph since n nodes requires n(n-1) number of connections.  Using event handles and some form of shared storage seems the most plausible solution right now...

**Updates**

- Does it have to be reliable and guaranteed? Yes, and no... Let's say that if I'm listening, and I'm responding in a reasonable time, then I should always get the message.
- What are the typical message sizes? less than 100 bytes including the message identifier and argument(s).  These are small.
- What message rate are we talking about?  Low throughput is acceptable, 10 per second would be a lot, average usage would be around 1 per minute.
- What are the number of processes involved?  I'd like it to handle between 0 and 50, with the average being between 5 and 10.

Comment: does it have to be reliable and guaranteed? And what are the typical message sizes? Reason I ask is, you could use a UDP port on the loopback device, and each "message" you want to send could be encapsulated in a single packet, any processes connected to that port on loopback, should in theory see that packet (as long as you've enabled reuseaddr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of anything that already exists, but you should be able to build something with a combination of:

- Memory mapped files
- Events
- Mutex
- Semaphore

This can be built in such a way that no "master" process is required, since all of those can be created as named objects that are then managed by the OS and not destroyed until the last client uses them.  The basic idea is that the first process to start up creates the objects you need, and then all other processes connect to those.  If the first process shuts down, the objects remain as long as at least one other process is maintaining a handle to them.

The memory mapped file is used to share memory among the processes.  The mutex provides synchronization to prevent simultaneous updates.  If you want to allow multiple readers or one writer, you can build something like a reader/writer lock using a couple of mutexes and a semaphore (see [Is there a global named reader/writer lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640122/is-there-a-global-named-reader-writer-lock/640368#640368)).  And events are used to notify everybody when new messages are posted.

I've waved my hand over some significant technical detail.  For example, knowing when to reset the event is kind of tough.  You could instead have each app poll for updates.

But going this route will provide a connectionless way of sharing information.  It doesn't require that a "server" process is always running.

For implementation, I would suggest implementing it in C++ and let the C# programs call it through P/Invoke.  Or perhaps in C# and let the C++ apps call it through COM interop.  That's assuming, of course, that your C++ apps are native rather than C++/CLI.

Comment: I finally travelled this road and the resulting class built upon named-events is located at: http://csharptest.net/browse/src/Library/IpcChannel/IpcEventChannel.cs

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried this, but in theory it should work. As I mentioned in my comment, use a UDP port on the loopback device. Then all the processes can read and write from/to this socket. As you say, the messages are small, so should fit into each packet - may be you can look at something like google's protocol buffers to generate the structures, or simply mem copy the structure into the packet to send and at the other end, cast. Given it's all on the local host, you don't have any alignment, network order type issues to worry about. To support different types of messages, ensure a common header which can be checked for type so that you can be backward compatible.

2cents...

Comment: Note from msdn: "If ExclusiveAddressUse is false, multiple sockets can use the Bind method to bind to a specific port; however only one of the sockets can perform operations on the network traffic sent to the port. If more than one socket attempts to use the Bind(EndPoint) method to bind to a particular port, then the one with the more specific IP address will handle the network traffic sent to that port." I'm not a socket expert, but is that going to work? And would that also work on ipv6 only hosts?

Comment: ah sorry, unicast packets will not be received by more than one connection, the second option is then to use a multicast group with all processes using the same port - but critically, set the TTL to 0 - this will prevent the packet from leaking to the network (I think that should work on windows)

Answer (score 0):

I think one more important consideration is performance, what message rate are we talking about and no. of processes?
Either way you are relying on a "master" that allows the communication needs, be it a custom service or a system provided(Pipes, Message Queue and such).

If you don't need to keep track and query for past messages, I do think you should consider a dead simple service that opens a named Pipe - allowing all other processes to either read or write to it as PipeClients. If I am not mistaken it checks on all items in your list.

Comment: The deployment for this application prevents us from the installation of services; however, a DCOM server would work as it would launch in-session with the user.  A single DCOM call to open the pipe when not available sounds like an option worth investigating.

Answer (score 0):

What your looking for is Mailslots!

See CreateMailslot:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365147(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: No, this won't allow multiple processes _on the same machine_ to receive a message from another process. Mailslot broadcasting works only across a network, and there can be only one receiver per network node.